# Evaluation Site Collection upgrade URL

Tags: 2013, site-collection, upgrade

I performed an evaluation site collection upgrade on my migrated 2010 site collection. The process completed but I am not able to browser my evaluation upgraded site collection. My site collection is a root site collection and created under a Web Application running on port 80.

The original site collection URL: http://sphqspdev01/

I tried with http://sphqspdev01/root-eval and other urls but doesn't work. Am I missing anything?

Comment: "http://sphqspdev01/sites/root-eval"

Answer (score 0):

If this is a root site collection it will be appended with "`/sites/root-eval`"